# Creating a GridView with columns generated at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a DataTable where the columns are generated programmatically at runtime. I then bind this DataTable to a GridView. What I'm wondering is how I can create the GridView to accommodate this, and if it's not possible, how I can output the DataTable into nicely formatted HTML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GridView has an [AutogenerateColums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx)-property for this purpose.
You could also generate the Columns on the fly, for example:

VB.NET

```
Dim tbl As New DataTable
tbl.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Int32))
tbl.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
tbl.Columns.Add("Birthday", GetType(Date))
Dim pers As DataRow = tbl.NewRow
pers("ID") = 1
pers("Name") = "Tim"
pers("Birthday") = New Date(1973, 6, 9)
```

use `AutoGenerateColumns` to let grid generate the column itself:

```
Me.GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
Me.GridView1.DataSource = tbl
Me.GridView1.DataBind()
```

or generate the columns dynamically

```
For Each col As DataColumn In tbl.Columns
    Dim field As New BoundField
    field.DataField = col.ColumnName
    field.HeaderText = col.ColumnName
    GridView1.Columns.Add(field)
Next
```

C#

```
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{    
    BoundField field = new BoundField();
    field.DataField = col.ColumnName;
    field.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
    GridView1.Columns.Add(field);
}
```

Comment: What if the data source for the new columns comes from somewhere other than the main data source of the GridView? Doesn't the gridview have to have only one data source before DataBind?

Comment: @Fernando68: sorry, i dont understand your requirement. Maybe it's best to create a real question and provide all necessary informations. Then i can try to answer. You could add a link to the question here to inform me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307156/gridview-how-to-add-columns-based-on-data-from-a-separate-data-source

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just set the DataTable as the gridview's DataSource. GridView has a `AutoGenerateColumns` property. Make sure it's set to `true` or pre-create columns manually yourself before performing the binding.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the other answers didn't cover this, here is how to set up a GridView with custom columns programatically.

```
    private GridView SetUpGrid()
    {
        GridView GView = new GridView();

        GView .ColumnHeaderToolTip = "MyToolTip";

        GridViewColumn gvc1 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc1.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Col1Name");
        gvc1.Header = "Column One";
        gvc1.Width = Double.NaN; // Auto-Size
        GView .Columns.Add(gvc1);
        GridViewColumn gvc2 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc2.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Col2Name");
        gvc2.Header = "Column Two";
        gvc2.Width = Double.NaN;
        GView .Columns.Add(gvc2);
        GridViewColumn gvc3 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc3.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Col3Name");
        gvc3.Header = "Column Three";
        gvc3.Width = Double.NaN;
        GView .Columns.Add(gvc3);
        GridViewColumn gvc4 = new GridViewColumn();
        gvc4.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Col4Name");
        gvc4.Header = "Column Four";
        gvc4.Width = Double.NaN;
        GView .Columns.Add(gvc4);

        return GView;
    }
```

Comment: GridViewColumn does not exist for web controls.