# Dynamically creating multiple textboxes depending on minimum number of characters in previous textbox/ javascript/asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic, textbox, dynamically-generated

Hi I have a webform in which i need to add multiple textboxes dynamically depending on the entry in previous textbox.. Even if one character is entered in the previous textbox it should generate new texbox beside it without losing the focus from previous textbox and it should allow me to enter as many characters without limiting..
Here is my code :

```
    getId = function ()
     {
        var id = 1;
        return function () 
        {
            id++;
        }
    }

    function CreateTextbox()
     {
        var box = document.getElementById("divCreateTextbox");
        var curr = 'txt' + getId();
        var inp = document.createElement('input');

        inp.type = 'text';
        inp.name = 'textfield';
        inp.setAttribute("id", curr);
        inp.setAttribute("minlength",'1');
        box.appendChild(inp);
        inp.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'moveOnMin(this)');
        inp.focus();

    }

    function moveOnMin(s)
     {
      if(s.value.length >= parseInt(s.getAttribute("minlength")))
      {

         CreateTextbox();
      }
```

The problem with the above code is, it is just allowing me to enter 1 character in one textbox and shifts the focus on new textbox. Everytime I try to enter more than one character in the textbox it creates new textboxes for each character. Any solutions ??

Comment: I am calling the function as

<Body>

 <div id="divCreateTextbox"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       window.onload = function ()
        {
           CreateTextbox()
       }
   </script>
</Body>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function CreateTextbox()
{
    var box = document.getElementById("divCreateTextbox");
    var curr = 'txt' + getId();
    var inp = document.createElement('input');

    inp.type = 'text';
    inp.name = 'textfield';
    inp.setAttribute("id", curr);
    inp.setAttribute("minlength",'1');
    box.appendChild(inp);
    inp.setAttribute('onkeyup', 'moveOnMin(this)');
    inp.setAttribute("textBoxAdded", "0");
    //inp.focus();

}

function moveOnMin(s)
{
    if (s.value.length == parseInt(s.getAttribute("minlength")) && s.getAttribute("textBoxAdded") == "0") 
{
        CreateTextbox();
        s.setAttribute("textBoxAdded", "1");
        s.focus();
    }
}
```

I have changed your code to:
 1. remain focus on existing TextBox; and
 2. let the TextBox added only once from every TextBox

Comment: I have tested it over IE 8.0. which browser you are testing on?

Comment: Plus as u said above " ... Everytime I try to enter more than one character in the textbox it creates new textboxes for each character.", means the code was working at your side earlier. I have just done few changes.

Comment: yes ali its creating a textbox initially but not generating new text box when i enter text in it.. have u seen the code m using to call the function ?

<asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Scan" ></asp:Label>

            <div id="divCreateTextbox"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function ()
           {
                CreateTextbox()
           }
            </script>

Comment: Sorry I didn't change few things in the new code.. it executes properly now :)

Comment: Thanks ! Can i add columns dynamically in Gridview as per the number of textboxes generated ??

Comment: Yes, refer this for sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696165/creating-a-gridview-with-columns-generated-at-runtime